# For each instance, take child img src and apply it to parent as background

Tags: jquery

I'm not very good with jQuery and I'm having a problem coming up with a solution. What I have is a blogroll with thumbnails, and I want to take the img src of the thumbnail, and apply it as the background of the parent element, for each instance.

In summary my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="main" class="site-content homepage">
    <article id="xxx">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <img class="post-img-thumbnail" src="xxx" />
        </div>
    </article>
   <article id="xxx">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <img class="post-img-thumbnail" src="xxxx" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <article id="xxx">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <img class="post-img-thumbnail" src="xxxxx" />
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

For each chunk of code like this on the blogroll, I want it to look like:

```
<div id="main" class="site-content homepage">
    <article id="xxx">
        <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background: url(xxx)'">

        </div>
    </article>
    <article id="xxx">
        <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background: url(xxxx)'">

        </div>
    </article>
    <article id="xxx">
        <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background: url(xxxxx)'">

        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

My jquery looks like so, but I know it isn't right. Not just because it doesn't work, but also because it doesn't really make sense. I don't know what the ID is going to be, so I can't figure out how to make it so that it just doesn't happen on the first post. Anyway:

```
var getImageSrc = $('#main.site-content.homepage .post-thumbnail > img').attr('src');
  $('#main.site-content.homepage .post-thumbnail > img').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
  }
  $('.post-img-thumbnail').remove();
```

EDIT: Above HTML was a summary, exact partial HTML is:

```
<article id="post-547" class="post-547 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-motivation">
    <figure class="post-thumbnail">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" src="http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar.jpg 1920w, http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar-300x169.jpg 300w, http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar-768x432.jpg 768w, http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar-1024x576.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px">
        <div class="post-date-thumbnail">
             <div class="post-date-day">25</div>
             <div class="post-date-month">Jan</div>
             <div class="post-date-year">2019</div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="entry-title-thumbnail"><a href="http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/index.php/2019/01/25/wake-up-world/" rel="bookmark">Wake Up World!</a></h2>  
    </figure>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".post-thumbnail").each(function(){
  var img = $(this).find("img")
  var pic = img.prop("src");
  $(this).attr("style","background: url(" + pic + ")");
  img.remove();
});
```

Comment: You may want to consider using `.css` instead of `.attt("style", ...)`, as if there is an existing `style` attribute on the element, that will erase it.

Comment: yes I also recommend .css('background', 'url(' +pic + ')');

Comment: Jan, code-only answers tend to be somewhat discouraged here. See Tyler's answer, which contains explanatory material. Would you be able to edit your answer to add something similar?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good use-case for jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

You can use it to loop through all `class="post-thumbnail"` elements, get the first `<img>`, get it's `src` attribute, apply it to the `post-thumbnail` element's CSS, and finally remove the `<img>`.

```js
$(".post-thumbnail").each(function() {
  let $img = $(this).children("img").first();
  let src = $img.attr("src");
  $(this).css("background",`url(${src})`);
  $img.remove();
});

console.log( $("article").html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-547" class="post-547 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-motivation">
  <figure class="post-thumbnail">
    <img width="1920" height="1080" src="http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar.jpg 1920w, http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar-300x169.jpg 300w, http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar-768x432.jpg 768w, http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/oscar-1024x576.jpg 1024w"
      sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px">
    <div class="post-date-thumbnail">
      <div class="post-date-day">25</div>
      <div class="post-date-month">Jan</div>
      <div class="post-date-year">2019</div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="entry-title-thumbnail"><a href="http://wordpress.xxxxxx.com/index.php/2019/01/25/wake-up-world/" rel="bookmark">Wake Up World!</a></h2>
  </figure>
</article>
```

Comment: I tested this, and it only works for the first instance.

Comment: @Xarcell I believe you're mistaken. Perhaps your HTML is not exactly as described in the question? I've posted the code in a runnable snippet - if you right click it and do Inspect Element, you will see that it does in fact work for all three images.

Comment: It's not exact, because it is too much HTML to post here. Maybe I can figure it out from the groundwork you laid.

Comment: @Xarcell I can change my answer if need be if you notice any differences in your HTML. I've added a `console.log()` to my example that outputs the changes to confirm that the code is in fact working.